# SQL Select Query into another query

Tags: sql, select

I am a beginner with SQL so apologise in advance if my terminology / coding is a little off, or maybe way off.
I have two queries which I would like to join into one. The first creating a list of productids which contain two specific processes.
I then want to use these productids in the second query.

Also is below correct?
group by products.productid having (sum(case when processid like 'pick%' then 1 else 0 end) + sum(case when processid like 'pack%' then 1 else 0 end) = 2)

Any help would be much appreciated, hope this makes sense.

```
SELECT
Products.ProductID
FROM Products
INNER JOIN Categories ON Products.Category = Categories.Category
INNER JOIN Boms ON Products.Product = Boms.Product AND Boms.BomVersion = Products.BomVersion
LEFT OUTER JOIN Products AS Comp ON Boms.Component = Comp.Product 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Processes  ON Boms.Process = Processes.Process
WHERE   
products.active = 1
and Categorys.Categoryid in ('5','20')
group by products.productid
having (sum(case when processid like 'pick%' then 1 else 0 end) + sum(case when processid like 'pack%' then 1 else 0 end) = 2)
order by products.productid


SELECT
Products.ProductID,
Products.productdescription,
Boms.Type As Type,
Comp.ProductId as Component,
Comp.productdescription,
Boms.Quantity,
BomVersions.BomVersionID,
Processes.processid,
Processes.ProcessDescription
FROM Products
INNER JOIN Categories ON Products.Category = Categories.Category
INNER JOIN Boms ON Products.Product = Boms.Product AND Boms.BomVersion = Products.BomVersion
LEFT OUTER JOIN Products AS Comp ON Boms.Component = Comp.Product 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Processes  ON Boms.Process = Processes.Process
INNER JOIN BomVersions ON Products.BomVersion = BomVersions.BomVersion
WHERE   
products.active = 1

order by products.productid, products.type,comp.productid
```

Comment: does it return the correct data?

Answer (score 0):

To combine them you could do the following.

```
SELECT b.*
FROM 
  (SELECT Products.ProductID FROM Products INNER JOIN ...) AS a
   INNER JOIN
  (SELECT Products.ProductID, Products.productdescription, Boms.Type As Type, ...) AS b
   ON a.ProductID = b.ProductID
```